# No Laravel 4, como posso converter o resultado do Model para XML?

Tags: php, xml, laravel, laravel-4

No Laravel, como eu poderia transformar o seguinte resultado abaixo para uma estrutura XML?

```
$usuarios = Usuario::with('nivel')->where(['status' => 1])->get()->toArray();

// Resultado:
[
   'usuarios' => [
       0 => [
                'id'   => 1,
                'nome' => 'Wallace',
                'nivel_id' => 4,
                'nivel'    => [
                    'id' => 4,
                    'nome' => 'Produção'
                ]


        ],
        1 => [
                'id'   => 2,
                'nome' => 'Wayne',
                'nivel_id' => 5,
                'nivel'    => [
                    'id' => 5,
                    'nome' => 'Recepção'
                ]


        ]
    ]
];
```

Como poderia utilizar os objetos `Model` e `Collection`, para poder converter para XML?

Observação: O `Model` é retornando pela chamada de `first`, e `Collection`, pela chamada de `get`.

Comment: Tu pode usar o package: https://github.com/SoapBox/laravel-formatter Com ele você consegue gerar os retornos para XML :)